# How get accessToken from the current user on onAuthStateChanged?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app is with React js, I am working with firebase and GitHub auth and I want to get the accessToken from the current user

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    // accessToken = ?
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

In login:

```js
firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(githubAuthProvider)
      .then((result) => {
        const token = result.credential.accessToken;
        const user = result.user;
        dispatch(login(user.uid, user.displayName, token));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "accessToken"?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish.  It might help if you link to any documentation that is unclear to you.

Comment: I am using auth with github, and that gives me a credencial with a token

Comment: I have updated my question with my code of login.. sorry.. I hope you can help me